# How do I make cmake output fortran .mod files into a mod dir?

Tags: cmake, fortran

Is there a cmake_mod_output_directory variable I can set? Right now cmake trows all *.mod files at the root of the CMAKE_BINARY_DIR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See target's property [Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#prop_tgt:Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY) or `CMAKE_Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY`.

Comment: How about the object files (*.o)?

Comment: It is not related to this, so feel free to open a new question